# What is the use of IQ stanaza in XMPP?

Tags: xmpp

What is the use of this stanza in XMPP?
In XMPP there are main three stanzas ,,, but I am not able to understand what is the use of IQ. Can anyone explain more on IQ stanza?

Answer (score 1):

IQ is for Info/Query stanza. IQ stanza is different as it expects a confirmation from the message sent.

This differs from other stanzas that are "send-and-forget" approach.